# Generate random numbers increasing by multiples of N in Java

Tags: java, random

I need to write a short randomizer which generates a random number between 1 to N where the random number is increasing by multiples of M.

For example: generate numbers between 1 and (N=30) increasing by multiples of (M=5). The only possible generated numbers can be then: 1,5,10,15,20,25 and 30. Hope you get what I mean :)

Normally if you use `new Random().nextInt(30)+1`, you get numbers increasing by multiples of 1 (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,etc.). That is not what I want.

Any help, links, or directions are very appreciated?

**EDIT**:

That the sequence of generated random numbers could include 1 not zero is one of the requirements of the method. Precisely, the sequence always starts with the lower bound (min). In the example the lower bound is 1 and therefore there can't be zero in the sequence. It's odd I know, but those are the requirements I have to follow ;)

Comment: This is not random number. This is sequence number, multiple of 5.

Comment: How is *1* a possible generated number as the numbers which are going to be generated need to be the multiples of *5*?

Comment: @R.J I know what you mean, but the requirements of this short method is to start by the lower bound, so 1 not zero :) And yes, it's a little bit odd ;)

Comment: @christian.vogel - Yeah it does seem a bit odd, but I guess you already got your answer below! :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could multiply the random value by 5. Since you want to have 1 instead of 0 just look for that value and alter it specifically:

```
static final Random random = new Random(System.currentTimeMillis());

public int random(int range, int multiple) {
    int value = random.nextInt(range / multiple) * multiple;
    return value == 0 ? 1 : value;
}
```

Comment: +1 I think the first value being 1 is a mistake by OP

Comment: No it isn't actually ;) As I said in previous comments, the requirements of the method indicates that it should start with the lower bound. In the example it is 1 not zero.

Comment: @Matthew Franglen Just to learn something new to me. Why did you give the Random constructor the current system time as parameter?

Comment: @christian.vogel The seed passed to the Random constructor is used to initialize the pseudo random generator. If you don't seed it with different values you may end up getting the same 'random' numbers. The current time in milliseconds is an adequate starting seed, as it will change each time you run the program.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html "If two instances of Random are created with the same seed, and the same sequence of method calls is made for each, they will generate and return identical sequences of numbers."

Answer (score 2):

I think that your example is a little bit flawed: the sequence should be (0, 5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30)

If I'm correct, you can then use:

```
new Random().nextInt(7) * 5; // will generate a number between 0 and 7 not included then multiply by 5 which should give what you want
```

If you want to start by 1, then just add it to the previous statement

Comment: Thanks, mate. Fully agree with the fact that it should start with 0, but the requirement of this method is that it should start with the lower bound and that is 1 not zero for the example.

Comment: @christian.vogel ok, makes sense then :-) I thought it might be some typo, hence my question

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    int N = 50;
    int M = 5;
    System.out.println(getRandomNumber(N, M));

}

static int getRandomNumber(int n, int m){
    Random r = new Random();
    int rnd = r.nextInt(n);
    return rnd%m == 0?rnd:getRandomNumber(n, m);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int n=Random.range(1,10);
n=n*100;
```

Comment: Please edit with more information. Code-only and "try this" answers are discouraged, because they contain no searchable content, and don't explain why someone should "try this". We make an effort here to be a resource for knowledge.